# S7 `NextMethod`-like dispatch for S3 classes

Tags: r, r-s7

I'm struggling how to specify to use the next available method for an S3 class.

Let's say I have a generic and a method that works for integers.

```r
library(S7)

new_sum <- new_generic("new_sum", "x")

method(new_sum, class_integer) <- function(x) sum(unclass(x))

new_sum(1:3)
#> [1] 6
```

Now, I'd like this function to work for factors as well. The integer method already has the `unclass()` to deal with potential factor input. If factors were S7 objects, the recommended approach would be to use the `super()` function to declare that the next method should be used. This doesn't work for S3 classes though.

```r
class_factor <- new_S3_class("factor")

method(new_sum, class_factor) <- function(x) {
  new_sum(super(x, class_integer))
}

f <- factor(LETTERS[1:3])

new_sum(f)
#> Error: `from` must be an <S7_object>, not a S3<factor>
```

One option is to cast the factor as an integer myself, however, in the real scenario I'd like to retain the class of `x`.

```r
method(new_sum, class_factor) <- function(x) {
  new_sum(as.integer(x))
}
#> Overwriting method new_sum(S3<factor>)

new_sum(f)
#> [1] 6
```

What does seem to work is to explicitly call the integer method, however this doesn't seem to be the intended design.

```r
method(new_sum, class_factor) <- function(x) {
  method(new_sum, class_integer)(x)
}
#> Overwriting method new_sum(S3<factor>)

new_sum(f)
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

What is the 'correct' approach for calling the next method for S3 classes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your question about the "correct" approach, but here is an idea.

Your object `f` returns `FALSE` from `S7_inherits(f)` since it's not an S7 object, so `super()` can't work.

`NextMethod()` won't work either, because it should only be called from an S3 method.

One kludgy solution is to edit the class of `x` to remove the current class (and, with this edit, earlier ones).  I doubt if this is "correct", but it appears to work:

```r
library(S7)

S3_super <- function(x, current_class) {
  current_entry <- which(class(x) == current_class)
  if (length(current_entry) == 0)
    stop("current class not found")
  class(x) <- class(x)[-seq_len(current_entry[1])]
  x
}

new_sum <- new_generic("new_sum", "x")

method(new_sum, class_integer) <- function(x) sum(unclass(x))

method(new_sum, class_factor) <- function(x) {
  if (S7_inherits(x)) 
    new_sum(super(x, class_integer)) 
  else
    new_sum(S3_super(x, "factor"))
}

x <- factor(LETTERS[1:3])
new_sum(x)
#> [1] 6
class(x) <- c("other_class", "factor")
new_sum(x)
#> [1] 6
class(x) <- c("factor", "other_class")
new_sum(x)
#> Error: Can't find method for `new_sum(S3<other_class>)`.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The error at the end is expected because you didn't define a default method.  You might argue it should go to the `class_integer` method instead, but I think it makes sense that once you know you don't have an S7 object, you should use pure S3 rules, and that's what it does.

If you don't want that, you could define an S3 "default" method, and have it strip off the class and then call the S7 generic again.  That does seem likely to get into a loop though...

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! I can imagine 2 issues with this approach. If `f` has class `c("factor", "other_class")`, it doesn't dispatch once `"factor"` is stripped and if it has class `c("other_class", "factor")` it is called repeatedly until `"factor"` is stripped. The second issue is that ideally just the dispatch is altered and the original class is retained.

Comment: Shouldn't it go to the default method in the first case?  Since you didn't define one, that should lead to a "no applicable method" error.  The second problem is a bug in my design:  it shouldn't remove just the first entry, it should remove all entries up to and including `"factor"`.    So `S3_super()` would need to be told which class it is working on, e.g. with a call like `S3_super(x, "factor")` in the `class_factor` method.  I'll fix it...